# Create one-to-one relationship T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables `CAR` and `CAR_BRAND`:

```
CREATE TABLE car
(
    car_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    car_brand int NOT NULL,
    tech_passport nvarchar(17) NOT NULL,
    vin_code nvarchar(17) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE car_brand
(
    car_brand_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name_brand nvarchar(15),
    country_brand nvarchar(20),
)
```

How to establish a one-to-one relationship between these two tables? One car has a one brand

Comment: That's a one-to-many relationship. A car only has one brand, but there can be many cars with the same brand.

Comment: @Guffa You're right. And how do the right?

Comment: With a foreign key constraint, so that the `car_brand` in the `car` table has to exist as `car_brand_id` in the `car_brand` table. See the answer by marc_s.

Answer (score 2):

Just like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Car
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Car_CarBrand
  FOREIGN KEY (Car_Brand) REFERENCES dbo.Car_Brand(Car_Brand_id)
```